# Importing MNIST dataset with Fortran

Tags: machine-learning, fortran, dataset, gfortran, mnist

A Linux/GFortran question.

I know exactly what my problem is but I can't figure out how to solve it...

I want to import the MNIST dataset images and labels into Fortran arrays to play around with Machine Learning algorithms using Fortran. I've done this with Python but I can't replicate reading the data files with Fortran.

The dataset files and file layout descriptions are at:

http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/

The 2 problems I'm struggling with are...

1) The data in the files is stored in unsigned bytes. I can't find a similar datatype in Fortran. I'm using integer(kind=1) to read the first 4 bytes successfully, which constitutes the file magic number, but I'm worried about incorrectly reading the value of one of these bytes into the signed integer(kind=1) datatype.

2) The data is stored in Big-Endian format. So when I read the number of images, rows and columns, which are stored in 4 byte integers, into my Little-Endian machine, I receive the obvious gobbledegook. Ideally, what I would like to be able to do is specify the Endiness of a variable to read from a file in an edit descriptor. Is this possible?

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: For the first issue, you can read the data "as is" in the corresponding integer from the [iso_c_binding](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ISO_005fC_005fBINDING.html#ISO_005fC_005fBINDING) module. What you do afterwards with the data remains to be determined. For the endianness, a non-portable solution is to use the [`convert`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/CONVERT-specifier.html#CONVERT-specifier) specifier.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I’m considering writing a small Python filter to convert the data into a Fortran friendly format to make the problem go away.

Comment: There is also the possibility of writing a C routine that would read the data and convert it to C signed integers before handing out control to the Fortran code.

Comment: Thanks Pierre. I’ll look into that too. In either Python or C, I think the best solution (for me) is to convert the data into a Fortran friendly format first, and then read it into my Fortran program. This will keep my Fortran code as clean and portable as possible.